# Changing link apperance with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do simple trick with .htaccess file, but with without success.
Generally I have PHP script that makes dynamically generated signatures and link looks like this:
example.com/signature/generate.php?name=%SomeUserName%

where %SomeUserName% is simply username e.g. Patison

and I'm trying to get:
example.com/signature/%SomeUserName% or (if necessary)
example.com/signature/generate/%SomeUserName%

Last code that I'm tried with no success:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/signature/generate.php?name=(*) /signature/$1 [L,NC]`

.htaccess is hard to understand for me.
So I have one more question. When someone use this link on another site he will render an image or it will work only on mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of approach you need:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signature/([^/\.]+)?$ signature/generate.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So anybody going to `signature/levi` will see `signature/generate.php?name=levi`